# Prevent delete or backspace key from triggering @input event

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2

I have two event listeners on an input component(@input and @keyup.delete). I am using the @input listener to detect keys and handle their usage accordingly, while I want to also detect when a user taps the delete or backspace button, so that I can change the index in a pin field.

#### BaseInputField.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <input
      ...
        :value="value"
        @keyup.delete="$emit('delete-or-backspace-key-pressed')"
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
       ...
    />
     ...
  </div>
</template>
```

#### ParentContainer.vue

```html
<BaseInputField
  ...
    @input="handleInput"
    @delete-or-backspace-key-pressed="handleDeletion"
  ...
/>
```

The problem is that pressing the `del` or `backspace` button also triggers the `@input` event, and it's messing with my implementation.

I would appreciate help on preventing this behaviour without the use of `Keycodes`, as according to Vue documentation, they are deprecated and may not work with newer browsers.

Comment: The [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0014-drop-keycode-support.md) states that they're dropping support for *using `keyCode` numbers as `v-on` modifiers* and for `Vue.config.keyCodes`. The aliases seem to be supported still.

Comment: Thank you, @tony19, for the information. It is well noted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `event.key` instead, but you need to use `@keydown` event instead of `@input`

`event.key` value will be `"Backspace"` or `"Delete"` if you press backspace / del respectively.

And you can do `preventDefault` on your `handleInput` function to prevent the input value deletion. So instead of passing `$event.target.value`, pass the whole `$event` object from the input

```html
@keydown="$emit('input', $event)"
```

and on your `handleInput` function:

```js
handleInput(e) {
      if (e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete") {
          return e.preventDefault(); // Don't do anything to the input value
      }
      const value = e.target.value;
      // do something with value
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snowflake-xpwqm?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you for replying. +1 for the answer. I now know that `e.key` is not deprecated. I was worried that there would be no alternative to `keyCode`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `BaseInputField.vue` to the following:

```js
<template>
  <input
    :value="value"
    @keyup.delete="triggerDBKey"
    @input="triggerInput"
    @paste="triggerPaste"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseInputField',
  props: {
    value: {type: String, default: ''}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      originalValue: this.value
    }
  },
  methods: {
    triggerInput(e) {
      if (this.originalValue.length > 0 && this.originalValue.length > e.target.value.length) return
      this.originalValue = e.target.value
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value)
    },
    triggerDBKey(e) {
      if (e.target.value === '') {
        this.originalValue = ''
      }
      this.$emit('delete-or-backspace-key-pressed')
    },
    triggerPaste(e) {
      this.$emit('paste')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Prevent the input event from being triggered by judging the content length before and after editing.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/preventing-deletebackspace-on-input-forked-wwg69?file=/src/components/ParentContainer.vue)

Comment: Thank you for replying. +1 for the answer. It didn't help me with my solution but it was enlightening.